# Combine Webpack Entry Points for production?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a web app with a large amount of JavaScript. Using Webpack, I have a single entry point (`app.js`). During development, using a watch task, every single JS change requires a new build of the bundle, and it takes 4 or 5 seconds to build it because of so much JavaScript. I'm trying to speed up this process during development.

I was thinking maybe there is a way to split up my entry point into many smaller entry points so that during development the build time is very short. And then when it comes time to deploy to production, there is maybe some task where is merges the entry points back into a single entry point again.

How would you go about doing this, beyond simply concatenating the JavaScript files together for production. Does Webpack have anything like this built-in or in a plugin?

Comment: did you try webpack-merge?

Comment: I don't see anything on the `webpack-merge` page about using it to merge together entry points. Not sure where to begin with that package.